# How to generate a transparent PNG image with LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, png, lwjgl

There's an entity of my LibGDX game I would like to render to a PNG. So I made a small tool that is a LibGDX app to display that entity and it takes a screenshot on F5. The goal of that app is only to generate the PNG.

```
camera.update();

Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();

animation.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 1000);
animation.draw(batch);

batch.end();

if(exporting)
    // export...
```

From that [wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Taking-a-Screenshot) I found out how to make a screenshot and by removing the for loop, I was able to get a screenshot that doesn't replace transparent pixels by black pixels.

```
byte[] pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), true);

Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);
PixmapIO.writePNG(Gdx.files.external("mypixmap.png"), pixmap);
pixmap.dispose();
```

It works well for the edges of the entity but not for the multiple parts inside.

Edges: (perfect)

[image: Edges]

Inside: (should not be transparent)

[image: Inside]

So I started playing with blending to fix that.
With

```
batch.enableBlending();
batch.setBlendFunction(
            exporting ? GL20.GL_ONE : GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, // exporting is set to true on the frame where the screenshot is taken
            GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This improved it a bit:

[image: Inside working]

But with images like glasses that are supposed to be transparent, it's opaque:

[image: Opaque glasses]

Instead of:

[image: Transparent glasses]

Any idea of what I should do to fix this? What I want is pretty standard, a transparent background with semi transparent images on top of it. I want it to behave just like a regular image software would with layers (like GIMP).

Comment: Wait, so it renders the transparency fine when you are in the app, but on taking the screenshot the transparency is screwed up?

Comment: @agillgilla Exactly, in the app it has a black transparent background so any transparent pixel remaining gets "merged" with the black

Comment: Hmmm... I'd almost be tempted to say that there's a bug in their `ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels()` function but that's unlikely.  I can't really see what you're doing wrong from what you've posted.  Have you tried `batch.enableBlending()` without the `batch.setBlendFunction()`?  And are you sure that `exporting` is true on the screenshot frame?

Comment: Just a tip, you should post the entire code with all mentioned parts together at the end. It may help you get answer more likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because written colors and alpha are both modulated by same function : SRC_ALPHA and ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.

You need to use glBlendFuncSeparate to achieve this. In your case :

```
batch.begin();

// first disable batch blending changes (see javadoc)
batch.setBlendFunction(-1, -1);

// then use special blending.
Gdx.gl.glBlendFuncSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);

... your drawings ...

batch.end();
```

In this way, colors channels still blended as usual but alpha channels are added (both source and destination).

Note that with libgdx 1.9.7+, the batch blending hack is not required anymore and could be :

```
batch.begin();

batch.setBlendFunctionSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);

... your drawings ...

batch.end();
```

There are some limitations in some cases though, please take a look at [my GIST](https://gist.github.com/mgsx-dev/9cab46e4c9583d1bbf9ea7db543c94bd) for more information.